# angular material md-input-container won't center vertically

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org) for designing my project. Now I want an input for searching in my toolbar, just like youtube.

My code:

```
<md-list flex-offset="10">
    <md-list-item layout-align="start center">
        <md-input-container md-no-float flex>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" flex>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button> test </md-button>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

The toolbar tags before my md-list looks like this:

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" flex style="max-height: 60px;">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
```

What I've tried:

- Wrapping it inside a normal div and setting layout-align to start, center.
- Using a form tag to wrap the input container.

Problem:

The input group won't center vertically, and this is what I'm after. Every other directive I've tried centers perfectly like the md-button.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Edit (Added picture comparing, md-input-container, input, md-button):

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did You try

```
md-input-container .md-errors-spacer{
 min-height: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

md-input-container has this rule from the specs {margin: 18px 0;} to account for validations, you can override it by making a custom clear-margin class {margin: 0 !important}.

Comment: Tried this using the following method: <md-input-container style="margin: 0 !important;">, sadly it didn't work.